# JPA connection error URL may be Invalid

Tags: jpa, openjpa

Development Environment
IBM RAD 8.5,
Websphere 8.5, 
JSF 2.0
JPA

I am getting the following error while I try to connect database in my JSF2.0 application

```
There were errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1325904 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" and URL "jdbc:derby:F:\TrainingDB;create=true".  You may have specified an invalid URL.
```

persistence.xml File is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="TrainingJPA">       
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.ewt.traningjpa.entity.EmpTbl</class>         
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:derby:F:\TrainingDB;create=true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have created the connecting using the database development option available in RAD 8.5

I know for sure that URL is correct. What could be other possible reason for this error.

TIA

Comment: Are there any other nested exceptions that might help shed some light on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Other possible causes:

- You don't have F: drive mapped on your PC
- You don't have sufficient permission to write file to F:\TrainingDB (Windows ACL / UAC maybe?)
- The file F:\TrainingDB is locked by other process